# how to implement this difference operation efficiently?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, series

I would like to build a data frame from an existing one, where each value per row is depending on the previous one. I have an initial value `v0` as starting point. Let me make an example

```
In [126]:import pandas as pd

In [127]: df = pd.DataFrame([1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3])

In [128]: df_result = df.copy()

In [129]: v0 = 10

In [130]: for i in range(1, len(df.index)):
     ...:     df_result.iloc[i, 0] = df.iloc[i, 0]*df_result.iloc[i-1, 0]
     ...: 

In [131]: df_result
Out[131]: 
       0
0  1.000
1  1.100
2  1.320
3  1.716
```

In [132]:

My question is about the for loop. How can I more efficiently writing this?

Comment: Answer was modify with first value `v0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need first [`numpy.insert`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html) value `v0` to first position and then call [`numpy.cumprod`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumprod.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1.0, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3], columns=['r'])
v0 = 10

df['n'] = np.cumprod(np.insert(df['r'].values[1:], 0, v0))
print (df)
     r      n
0  1.0  10.00
1  1.1  11.00
2  1.2  13.20
3  1.3  17.16
```